# Dock Icon Show Desktop

Tags: icon, desktop

Is it possible to create a dock icon that shows the desktop?

Ideally I'm looking for 10.5.6 support and up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 options.

You can either [call](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/105361/terminal-commands-for-application-windows-and-show-desktop-in-mountain-lion) `key code 60`(or the equivalent key show desktop is set).

Alternatively you can call Mission Control as described [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/105361/terminal-commands-for-application-windows-and-show-desktop-in-mountain-lion).

```
/Applications/Mission\ Control.app/Contents/MacOS/Mission\ Control 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create an AppleScript to minimise all windows and then pin it in your dock. An example of a script that minimises all windows can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8620605/applescript-to-minimize-all-visible-windows-is-very-slow-how-to-speed-it-up):

1. Create a new Automator application that executes an AppleScript

[image]

2. Export this to save it as an app somewhere (File > Export)
3. Add the exported application to your dock
4. The first time the application runs, it will request the ability to control your computer, you need to allow it so that it can minimise apps.

You can optionally set a nice icon for this application, by selecting it and pressing `cmd`+`i` to open the info window and then pasting your custom icon over the current icon:

[image]

Comment: You could do the same and hide the application instead of minimising.

Comment: +1 although I would ideally like to invoke "SHow Desktop" similar to if you pressed F11 on the keyboard or some equivalent.